# Having multiple clickable segment in a html canvas circle that fills color in each area that is clicked

Tags: css, html, canvas

I need to create a rating circle with rating ranging between 1 to 5. 
I would like to have a circle with 5 different segments. On click of each segment the color of the segment should be filled. Being new to design a canvas, I'm unable to figure out in splitting a canvas into multiple clickable segments.
Like the image

[image]

I was able to attain this by using css with divs in place

```
<div class="main">
<div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
<div class="quarter quarter2"></div>
<div class="quarter quarter3"></div>
<div class="quarter quarter4"></div>
<div class="cutout"></div>
</div>
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashokmohank/u78bQ/414/)

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. please before asking any further questions read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [help]. Actually if you feel lazy simply take a look how other people ask questions here.

Comment: Have you tried by simply using SVG (instead of Canvas)?

Comment: <canvas id="counter1" width="240" height="240"></canvas> 
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('counter1');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width /2;
      var y = canvas.height/2;
      var radius = 75;
      var startAngle = 2.1 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 3.9 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      context.lineWidth = 15;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.stroke();
</script>

Comment: I was just able to draw a circle and not sure on how to split those in to segments

Comment: Thanks SVG could be a better option

Answer (score 3):

I like you because you are steadfast in your purpose after many days. i decide completion my answer. 
i hope this answer was complete.

```js
var context;
var canvas_width;
var canvas_height;
var canvas_offset_left;
var canvas_offset_top;
var center_location_x = 100;
var center_location_y = 100;
var item_selected;

colors = ["#FFF212", "#A8CF45", "#F58634" , "#FFF212", "#A8CF45", "#F58634"];

var third = 1/3;
var width = 70;

window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas_width = canvas.width;
  canvas_height = canvas.width;
  canvas_offset_left = canvas.offsetLeft;
  canvas_offset_top = canvas.offsetTop;
  drawAll();
};

function drawAll()
{
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle='#FFFFFF';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas_width,canvas_height);
  context.closePath();

  for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
     draw_item(i, false);
}

//handle mouse event ---------------
var cursor_x=0;
var cursor_y=0;

function move(e)
{
e=e||event;
cursor_x=e.pageX;
cursor_y=e.pageY;
if(e.target.id != 'canvas')
    drawAll();
}
document.onmousemove=move;
//---------------------------------


document.getElementById('canvas-div').onmousemove = hoverAction;
function hoverAction()
{
    var offset_x = (center_location_x)+canvas_offset_left;
    var offset_y = (center_location_y)+canvas_offset_top;

    move_degree = Math.atan2( cursor_x - offset_x ,  -(cursor_y - offset_y) );

      drawAll();
      switch(true)
      {
        case (move_degree > 0 && move_degree < (Math.PI/3) ):
           draw_item(0, true);
        break;
        case (move_degree > (Math.PI/3) && move_degree < (Math.PI/3)*2 ):
           draw_item(1, true);
        break;
        case (move_degree > (Math.PI/3)*2 && move_degree < Math.PI ):
           draw_item(2, true);
        break;
        case (move_degree > -Math.PI && move_degree < -Math.PI+(Math.PI/3) ):
           draw_item(3, true);
        break;
        case (move_degree > -Math.PI+(Math.PI/3) && move_degree < -Math.PI+(Math.PI/3)*2 ):
           draw_item(4, true);
        break;
        case (move_degree > -Math.PI+(Math.PI/3)*2  && move_degree < 0 ):
           draw_item(5, true);
        break;
      }


}

function draw_item(item, isHover)
{
     item_selected = item;
     var color =  isHover ? "#0C10CC" : colors[item];
     context.beginPath();
     switch(item)
      {
        case 0 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60, 1.5*Math.PI, (Math.PI*1.5)+(third*Math.PI) );
        break;
        case 1 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60, (Math.PI*1.5)+(third*Math.PI), (Math.PI*1.5)+ (third*Math.PI*2));
        break;
        case 2 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60, (Math.PI*1.5)+(third*Math.PI*2), (Math.PI*0.5));
        break;
        case 3 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60, Math.PI*0.5,  (Math.PI*0.5)+(third*Math.PI));
        break;
        case 4 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60, (Math.PI*0.5)+(third*Math.PI), (Math.PI*0.5)+(third*Math.PI*2));
        break;
        case 5 :
          context.arc(100, 100, 60,  (Math.PI*0.5)+(third*Math.PI*2), (Math.PI*1.5));
        break;
      }
      context.strokeStyle = color;
      context.lineWidth = width;
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
}
```

```css
 #canvas-div
 {
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width : 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div id="canvas-div"><canvas height="200" width="200" id="canvas" onclick="alert(item_selected+1)"> your browser not support</canvas></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for exactly implementing it ! I have tried using divs and was able to make with for different div elements. [Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashokmohank/u78bQ/413/)  shows my way of implementation. Now I'm trying to make it with 5 div elements.

Comment: I would actually want the segments to be clickable. I'm not able to render the canvas element as clickable.